# Bulk insert breaks when adding DATAFILETYPE='widenative'

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have this little sql script to import a semicolon separated file into a specific table of my database:

```
BULK
INSERT foo_bar
FROM 'C:\Users\JohnDoe\projects\foo\ftp-data-importator\bar.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
FIRSTROW = 2,
MAXERRORS = 100000,
ERRORFILE = 'c:\temp\foobar_bulk_log.txt'
)
GO
```

And it's working like a charm.
The only problem is that some special unicode characters like ó or é are not being inserted respecting the encoding of the file.

So I added the next line between the WITH keyword parentheses:

`DATAFILETYPE = 'widenative'`

And instead of respecting the encoding is breaking the whole execution and giving me the next error:

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 5, Line 5 The bulk load failed. The column
>   is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the
>   field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly. Msg 7301,
>   Level 16, State 2, Line 5 Cannot obtain the required interface
>   ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server
>   "(null)".

Where is the problem?

Comment: I would never think SQL server bulk insert is working like a charm, but sometimes it does. Is your file really a Unicode file with a byte order mark? Even in that case I had problems with SQL server. If your file is an ANSI text then instead of DataFileType, try using CodePage=1250. BTW, with Unicode you would use widechar.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it replacing the line `DATAFILETYPE = 'widenative'` with `CodePage=1252`. Post the comment as answer if you want. You were aiming in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of DataFileType try using CODEPAGE=1252.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying `widechar` instead of `widenative`  Your original statement is using character mode, not native BCP format.  Also, ensure the source file is Unicode (not UTF-8).

Comment: So, if i want to import a utf-8 file? What do I need to do?

Comment: @PicaCodigo, UTF-8 support is introduced in SQL 2016.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx.